# How to stop wcf service generating entity framework references

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have a WCF service containing an entity framework project.

I also have DTO classes that I use to expose the data. The entity objects get mapped to DTO objects.

When I generate a service proxy I am seeing both the entity object and the DTO object.

If I have a table called Product I get a Product and a Product1 reference.

This didn't use to happen.

What have I done to cause this and how can I stop my entity objects being exposed?

More Info:

When EF generates a model object from the database, it adds a data contract attribute like this:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="KernMobile_V5Model", Name="JobMaster")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class JobMaster : EntityObject
```

I assume this means that it will be exposed by the service?

Comment: What does the product DTO's look like?  Is it possible you are using enum's from EF that are declared inside EF classes?  Any DTO properties declared of an EF type?

Comment: Seems to be the generation of the proxy that causes it. I have an old version of my client. When I generate the proxy from that all is well - no duplication. When I generate a proxy from the latest client I get duplication. What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service only exposes objects that are used in the service operations, or are specified as a known type to be exposed.

If your client proxy is generating an object for these entity framework objects, you must be exposing them through your service somehow. This can be as request or response objects, or as properties on those objects.

Comment: That was exactly the correct answer. I had accidentally referenced an entity object that pulled almost the entire entity object graph with it.